# Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile on project xyz: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-plugin, java-11

I'm having issue to deploy my spring project with maven wrapper in Heroku.

and I got failure output listed as:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project xyz: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR] 
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote: 
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
```

Here is my POM.XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>sia</groupId>

    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>

    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>xyz</name>

    <description>Project to sell Wine</description>

    <properties>
        <java.runtime.version>11</java.runtime.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
              <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
              </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>
                      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                    </exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
             <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
             <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>3.0.7</version>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>



        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
      <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestone</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
       </pluginRepository>
     </pluginRepositories>



</project>
```

Also downgraded the JDK from 1.11 to 1.8 and my JAVA_HOME path = /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

And my Maven version:

```
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_382, vendor: Private Build, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_AU, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "6.2.0-34-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

I have no issue to deploy locally, but when I push to the Heroku, it fails every time.

Seems it's trying to Installing Maven 3.9.4 when initialized.

```
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Java app detected
remote: -----> Installing OpenJDK 1.8... done
remote: -----> Installing Maven 3.9.4... done
```

Wondering if this is something wrong to set the JDK path or my plugins are not right about to point to Maven 3.8.1

Comment: Based on the error message `compiling: invalid target release: 11 ->` ... why using such an old JDK 8 verison and also the setting `java.version.runtime` seemed to be wrong... another issue is that you are using very old version of spring boot... it's long out of support (https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support)

Comment: My project requires 1.8 compiler. I found my Javac is stilling point to java11, and there are some files missing from java8. Once reinstall java8 and change javac to 1.8 I have no issue to deploy.

Comment: Very important Spring Boot is not supported anymore ... as I mentioned. Also using old Maven versions and probaly old plugin versions as well https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ If you need to compile on JDK 8 you should configure the properties `<maven.compiler.target>` and `maven.compiler.source` accordingly (https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html) and don't define it in the configuration of the maven-compiler-plugin etc...